# Add a span with custom id in Spring sleuth (2.1.0)

Tags: java, spring-boot, trace, spring-cloud-sleuth

I wanted to add a logic in my application such that if my HttpServletRequest has "traceId" in header, I dont want to create new traceId and carry the same id over to next services.

I can do that by creating a filter before TraceFilter which consumes this traceId from request and creates a span with same id. Can someone help in achieving this?

I have following doubts:

1. `SPAN_CREATION`: How to create a span with existing traceId?
2. `SPAN_KEY`: How do I set that span into my request so that sleuth takes it up and doesnt create a new span?

I am trying following code:

```
@Order(TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration.TRACING_FILTER_ORDER - 1)
public class HeaderInjectFilter  extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String searchId = extractTraceIdFromRequest((HttpServletRequest) request);
        if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(searchId)){
            request.setAttribute(SPAN_KEY, spanForId(searchId));
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private Span spanForId(final String traceId) {
        return SPAN_CREATION;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.